# Are there any items or gear that are known to be removed from the Tiny Tina Oneshot?

Tags: version-differences, tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep

Having played a bit of the *Tiny Tina’s Assault on Dragon Keep Oneshot*, I’ve noticed certain unique items dropping that are normally quest items or in restricted loot pools (such as the Teeth of Terramorphous). I do appreciate that we’re not strictly limited to gear that’s part of the DLC, and just found a [guide that notes some new loot farms specific to the standalone](https://mentalmars.com/guides/tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep-legendary-loot-locations/).

However, I want to know whether there are any items that are **known** not to be included for some reason or another.

As I understand, things like the Bee shield haven’t necessarily been removed, but may have had their loot pool changed so that they don’t drop commonly from Treants, so those don’t count. I want to know if there are builds that I should 100% give up on due to the gear simply not being present.